# How to replace a value with the output of a command in a text file?

Tags: bash, replace, sed

I have a file that contains:

```php
<?php return 0;
```

I want to replace in bash, the value `0` by the current timestamp.

I know I can get the current timestamp with:

```sh
date +%s
```

And I can replace strings with `sed`:

```sh
sed 's/old/new/g' input.txt > output.txt
```

But how to combine the two to achieve what I want? Solutions not involving `sed` and `date` are welcome as well, as long as they only use shell tools.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In general, do use this syntax:

```
sed "s/<expression>/$(command)/" file
```

This will look for `<expression>` and replace it with the output of `command`.

---

For your specific problem, you can use the following:

```
sed "s/0/$(date +%s)/g" input.txt > output.txt
```

This replaces any `0` present in the file with the output of the command `date +%s`. Note you need to use double quotes to make the command in `$()` be interpreted. Otherwise, you would get a literal `$(date +%s)`.

If you want the file to be updated automatically, add `-i` to the sed command: `sed -i "s/...`. This is called in-place editing.

---

#### Test

Given a file with this content:

```
<?php return 0;
```

Let's see what it returns:

```
$ sed "s/0/$(date +%s)/g" file
<?php return 1372175125;
```

Comment: Oh, you just wanted to change `0`, not the whole `<?php return...`! Just updated my answer.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to update your answer to reflect my exact use case :-) Not sure why someone downvoted you without a comment, by the way.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't understand that downvote... Anyway, good point editing with the exact use case, @Benjamin! Regards

Comment: How would one make this work if the command had to be invoked every time there is a match ?

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier I believe exactly like I am showing in my answer. I would need more details!

Comment: No, in your answer the command `"$(date +%s)"` is executed before `sed` is even run and its result is substituted by your shell. I could do it with `perl` instead: `perl -pe 's|0|`uuidgen`/g` replaces each 0 by a different invocation of uuid.

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier oh, I see. You are right. Then you can probably use `/e` as seen in posts like [How to change date format in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34071098/1983854). This will for sure run the command on every line. However, I doubt is going to be nicer than in Perl :)

Comment: Sorry, formatting was bad: `perl -pe 's|0|\`uuidgen\`|g'`

Comment: @Jean-Michaël Celerier this doesn't run uuidgen mutiple times: ```~ echo '00' | perl -pe "s|0|`uuidgen` |g"```

```6b748ce4-5e14-4939-9367-ede54b112e30 6b748ce4-5e14-4939-9367-ede54b112e30```

Comment: sorry, command is missing a "e". Also it must be single quotes, not double quotes.  `echo 000 | perl -pe 's/0/\`uuidgen\`/ge'`

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier are you replying to peetasan's comment? Better `@ping` them so they see your reply (quite a time-elapsed conversation you are having ;-D)

Answer (score 2):

When the replacement string has newlines and spaces, you can use something else.
We will try to insert the output of `ls -l` in the middle of some template file.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0;next}
    {print}
    /Insert index here/ {for (i=1; i <= length(a); i++) { print a[i] }}'
    <(ls -l) template.file
```

or

```
sed '/^Insert after this$/r'<(ls -l) template.file
```

Comment: Thanks, but the awk example won't work for me, it waits forever. If I remove the line breaks, it runs, but doesn't do anything with the file. Also, what is 'index'?

Comment: The awk searches for some string. In this exampl the string is `Insert index here`. When this line is found in `template.file` it will try to insert tje listing. Perhaps i should have said `/Insert <ls -l> here/`.